# Timestamp that changes based on a Dropdown List and 2 Tickboxes / Checkboxes

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hello everyone can someone assist me with a FORMULA or Script? Any assistance will be warmly appreciated.
I am trying to set a timestamp that changes base on a dropdown list and two tickboxes/ Checkboxes

Comment: Unfortunately I having trouble using this script on trigger function but thanks for your input

Answer (score 0):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == "Sheet0" && e.range.columnStart < 4) {
    let ts = new Date();
    if(e.value == "TRUE") {
      sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,4).setValues(ts);
    } else if(e.value) {
      sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,4).setValues(ts);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Results from running your Google Script 9:15:55 PM Error 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined
onEdit @ Code.gs:2

Comment: I presume you attempted to run the function without providing the event object that the trigger provides.  If that's the case then that won't work.  The function was meant to be run from the onEdit trigger.  However, it can be run through a intermediary function if that function also provide the event object.